# No network out of the sudden on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, networking, server, dhcp

Recently, I replaced my network card and had few issues with the new card and the network connection on the office Intel Xeon 5500/Core i7 white box server running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.10. I ended up uninstalling the network manager and set the network from `/etc/network/interfaces`. So far so good.

Then I started to recognize that static IP becomes dynamic automatically! I had to manually shift from bring the network down (by `ifdown eth0`) and get it back up (by `ifup eth0`) at first. After some research I ended up uninstalling the dynamic IP (dhcp option) and that fixed the problem. The server was always on static IP. Everything was perfect for about a month. After the holidays I came back to office and now there is NO CONNECTION AT ALL! :(

from /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# The loopback network interface 
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 
auto eth0 

# iface eth0 inet dhcp 
iface eth0 inet static 

address 128.95.165.148 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
network 128.95.165.0 
broadcast 128.95.165.255 
gateway 128.95.165.100 
dns-morgul 128.95.120.1 129.95.112.1
```

Comment: I am suspicious of line four.

Comment: That is what I have in that file (auto eth0)

Answer (score 1):

You must update to Ubuntu 13.10, support for 12.10 is dead and you will find a performance boost and a better compatibility with your new network card, I recommend to clean install Ubuntu 13.10 because of the changes you have made, save all your data, clean install and you will see your new wifi card running out of the box.

Comment: No! clean install is not an option for me. There are TBs of data on this server that I don't want to do clean install and backing up will be a pain in the back.